# When does the “Kernel functor” produce an exact row?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

*(I apologize in advance if there's a way simpler way to formulate things, or an obvious result that I'm just missing.)*

Let $\require{AMScd}\newcommand{\C}{\mathscr C}\C$ be an abelian category.

By the universal property of the kernel, a commutative diagram

\begin{align}
\begin{CD}
  X_1 @>\sigma_X>> X_2\\
  @Vf_1VV @Vf_2VV \\
  Y_1 @>\sigma_Y>> Y_2
\end{CD}
\end{align}

gives rise to a morphism $\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker} \Ker f_1 \to \Ker f_2$.
This is done as follows:
If $\kappa_i\colon \Ker f_i\to X_i$ is the respective kernel injection and $;$ denotes covariant composition, we can consider the composition
$\kappa_1 ; \sigma_X ; f_2 = \kappa_1;f_1;\sigma_Y = 0;\sigma_Y = 0$.
Hence $\kappa_1;\sigma_X$ factors through $\kappa_2$ by means of a (unique) morphism
$\Ker(\sigma)\colon \Ker f_1 \to \Ker f_2$.

In fact, this assignment ist functorial, so $\Ker\in \C^{\ast \to \ast}$, where the superscript denotes the small category containing two objects and one non-identity morphism.

> To verify that this turns into a functor, consider the diagram
> \begin{align}
> \begin{CD}
>   \Ker f_1 @>\Ker\sigma>> \Ker f_2 @>\Ker \tau>> \Ker f_3 \\
>   @V\kappa_1VV @V\kappa_2VV @V\kappa_3VV\\
>   X_1 @>\sigma_X>> X_2 @>\tau_X>> X_3\\
>   @Vf_1VV @Vf_2VV @Vf_3VV\\
>   Y_1 @>\sigma_Y>> Y_2 @>\tau_Y>> Y_3,
> \end{CD}
> \end{align}
> whose upper squares commute by the definition of $\Ker \sigma$.
> We now see that $\Ker \sigma;\Ker \tau$ factors $\kappa_1;(\sigma_X\tau_X) = \kappa_1;(\sigma;\tau)_X$, but this is the property that uniquely defines $\Ker (\sigma;\tau)$.

**Question**

> In the former diagram, under which condition is the top row exact?

The reason I ask is that chaining epis $\alpha;\beta\colon A\to B\to C$ gives rise to natural transformations of morphisms $\sigma\colon\alpha \to \alpha;\beta$
and $\tau\colon \alpha;\beta \to \beta$ as depicted here:
\begin{align}
\begin{CD}
  \Ker \alpha @>\Ker\sigma>> \Ker \alpha;\beta @>\Ker \tau>> \Ker \beta \\
  @V\kappa_1VV @V\kappa_2VV @V\kappa_3VV\\
  A @= A @>\alpha>> B\\
  @V\alpha VV @V\alpha;\beta VV @V\beta VV\\
  B @>\beta >> C @= C.
\end{CD}
\end{align}

Interpreting the top row e.g. in the case of $R$-modules (and treating $\Ker$ as a literal zero set) enlightens us as follows:

- $\Ker \sigma$ is just „subspace inclusion“ since every element in the kernel of $\alpha$ is already in the kernel of $\alpha;\beta$
- $\Ker \tau$ maps an $x\in \Ker\alpha;\beta$ to $\alpha(x)\in \Ker\beta$, so we just have restriction of $\alpha$ to $\Ker\alpha;\beta = \alpha^{-1}(\Ker \beta)$.
  Therefore $\Ker (\Ker \tau) = \Ker \alpha\vert_{\alpha^{-1}(\Ker \beta)} = \Ker \alpha$, so we indeed have an exact sequence.

The corresponding dual statement is very natural however:
Taking instead cokernels and monos (interpreting the monos $\beta',\alpha'$ as subspace inclusions $C\subset B \subset A$) yields an exact sequence $\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{Coker}\coker\beta' \to \coker\beta';\alpha' \to \coker\alpha'$, which is precisely the statement that $(A/C)/(B/C)\simeq A/B$.

This suggests to me that the top row being exact gives us some sort of generalized isomorphism theorem, but I am unsure whether one can generalize the demonstrated diagram chase.  I've tried to look for something like a snake lemma, but failed to find something helpful.

Comment: You can use that kernel is a limit. Limits preserve limits, hence kernel does preseve kernels and is left exact. I do not expect that kernel is right exact in general, but I don t have a conterexample at hand right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The snake lemma tells you exactly what you want to know. The exactness of the kernel sequence on top tells you that kernel is left exact as a functor from the arrow category. The existence of the connecting morphism tells that kernel is not right exact in general.